# pass custom environment variables to System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

I'm working on an app that invokes external processes like so:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(PathToExecutable, Arguments){
     ErrorDialog = false,
     RedirectStandardError = true,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory
 };

using (Process process = new Process()) {
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

One of the processes I'm calling depends on an environment variable that I'd rather not require my users to set.  Is there any way to modify the environment variables that get sent to the external process?  Ideally I'd be able to make them visible only to the process that's running, but if I have to programmatically set them system-wide, I'll settle for that (but, would UAC force me to run as administrator to do that?)

ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables is read only, so a lot of help that is...

Comment: Do you not have control over the external process? Otherwise if you do why can't you pass it as an argument then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add values to it though.

From [MSDN ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx):

> Although you cannot set the EnvironmentVariables property, you can
>   modify the StringDictionary returned by the property. For example, the
>   following code adds a TempPath environment variable:
>   `myProcess.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("TempPath", "C:\\Temp")`.
>   You must set the **UseShellExecute** property to **false** to start the
>   process after changing the EnvironmentVariables property. If
>   **UseShellExecute** is **true**, an InvalidOperationException is thrown when
>   the Start method is called.

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow I missed that.  I think I stopped reading at the line above that, "The default is null".  Sounds like the default value is actually an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables using the indexer:

```
process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables['name'] = value;
```